# adding an Interface

Tags: c#, http, request

My main Program.cs is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HTTPrequestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lstWebSites = new List<string>
            {
                "www.amazon.com",
                "www.ebay.com",
                "www.att.com",
                "www.verizon.com",
                "www.sprint.com",
                "www.centurylink.com",
                "www.yahoo.com"
            };
            string filename = @"RequestLog.txt";
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
                {
                    foreach (string website in lstWebSites)
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                        {
                            MyWebRequest request = new MyWebRequest();
                            request.Request();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have a class, and this is where the errors are.

The GetList() error - 'HTTPrequestApp.Program' does not contain a definition for 'GetList'

The client2 error - The name 'client2' does not exist in the current content

MyWebRequest.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HTTPrequestApp
{
    public class MyWebRequest : HTTPrequestApp.IWebRequest
    {
        public void Request()
        {
            List<string> lstWebSites = Program.GetList();
            using (var client = new TcpClient(lstWebSites[1], 80))
            {
                using (NetworkStream stream = client2.GetStream())
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                using (StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    writer.AutoFlush = true;
                    writer.WriteLine("GET / HTTP/1.1");
                    writer.WriteLine("HOST: {0}:80", lstWebSites[1]);
                    writer.WriteLine("Connection: Close");
                    writer.WriteLine();
                    writer.WriteLine();

                    string theresponse = reader2.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(theresponse);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, I have an Interface. Is this done correctly?

If I am doing something incorrectly please help me, how should I fix it?

IWebRequest.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HTTPrequestApp
{
    interface IWebRequest
    {
        void Request();
    }
}
```

What I have to do is: send HTTP request to get the initial page and get back the HTTP response. Save it into the .cvs file. Check that it is a 200 response code and time how long it took to retrieve the response. I have to get the response 4 times from each of those websites in my list. 
Please help me.

Comment: Unless you *want* to do the HTTP programming from scratch, I suggest using one of the native classes. http://www.diogonunes.com/blog/webclient-vs-httpclient-vs-httpwebrequest/ Using WebRequest, you can probably do what you want in a few lines of code https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, this explains everything in a simple way...

Comment: When I am trying to add the Webclient in MyWebRequest I am getting the same erros as I mentioned above, I have the using references, and the System.dll's all checked. Any suggestions? Also, did I add my interface correctly?

Comment: See my complete code example below. You don't need to implement interfaces, just make HTTP calls.

Comment: I know I don't need to, I had an existing project which does not use interfaces, but my manager wants me to add an interface to this. We are going to build upon this project for later use.

Comment: I see. Well, just use IWebRequest and implement with WebRequest as below. Done. :)

Answer (score 1):

First about your errors :

1. The provided code does not contain GetList method in Program class as the code shared contains the only main method which defines your websites.
2. The line `using (var client = new TcpClient(lstWebSites[1], 80))` creates client object instead of client2.

Another point, instead of writing to open TCPClient connection to read the response of website you can use `HttpClient` or `WebRequest` in-built classes to achieve your functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full example of what I mean. Keep adding all the websites you want to lstWebSites, and instead of dumping the HTML results to the console, you can write them to a file.

```
var lstWebSites = new List<string>
        {
            "https://www.stackoverflow.com",
            "https://www.google.com"
        };
foreach (string website in lstWebSites)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(website);
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    ((HttpWebRequest)request).UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36";   // Lie
    var response = request.GetResponse();
    if (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("***** {0} *****", website));
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());  // Dump HTML response
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks good, I was trying to use this code but Console.WriteLine($"***** {website} *****"} is giving me a )expected ERROR.

Comment: Try it now. I used the more modern string format syntax.